# Determine whether the following set is compact: $\{(x,y)\} \in \mathbb{R^2} : 2x^2 - y^2 \leq 1\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, compactness

Determine whether the following set is compact: $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : 2x^2 - y^2 \leq 1\}$

The question is asking to just determine, but I would like to know how would you SHOW that this set is compact?

**Defn:** A set $A$ is compact $\Leftrightarrow$ the set is closed and bounded.

**Defn:** A set is closed if it contains all of its limit points

**Defn:** A set is bounded if $\exists$ R such that the set $A$ is contained in the $B_{R}(0)$

So I am able to reason out that this set is compact. The set is bounded because there does exist an $R$ in this case $R = 1$ where this set is contained within $B_{1}(0) \in \mathbb{R^2}$.

As for closed I would have to somehow show that my set contains all of its limit points. To do that I would have to know what all of the limit points are, but that is impossible. Perhaps I could use contradiction and say something along the lines that if a limit point was not in the set it would violate the conditions of the given set. Specifically $$2x^2 - y^2 \leq 1$$

This is how I would think out the problem, but I know this is not formal, so how would I formalize this into a proper proof? What am I missing in my though pattern?

Comment: The set is not compact because it is not bounded. To see this, take any arbitrary $x\in\mathbb R$ and define $y\equiv \sqrt{2}x$. Then, as one can easily check, $(x,y)$ is in the set, yet its Euclidean norm $$\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{3}|x|$$ can be made arbitrarily large by choosing $x$ accordingly.

Comment: "there does exist an R in this case R=1 where this set is contained"  If $(x,y) = (k,k \sqrt 2)$ then $2x^2 - y^2 = 0\le 1$ but $||(x,y)|| = \sqrt {k^2 + 2k^2} = k\sqrt 3$.  If $k > 1$ then $||(x,y)|| > 1$.

Comment: " to know what all of the limit points are, but that is impossible" why do you say that?

Comment: @fleablood looking at the set I feel that you can make almost any collection of numbers a sequence and since there is an infinite amount of choices I am not sure how you can illustrate all of the limit points.

Comment: If we can't say anything about infinite sets we might as well give up on mathematics.

Comment: If $2x^2 - y > 1$ then then let $\epsilon < (2x^2 - y -1)$ and show that if $(k,j) \in B_{\epsilon}(x,y)$ then $2k^2 - j > 1$.  That's easy to do.  So $(x,y) $ is not a limit point.  So the set is closed.

Comment: Even easier, $(0, y)$ is in the set for each $y$.

Comment: @fleablood I'm sorry I'm really trying to grasp what you explained, but it is not clicking for me. Are you using a contrapositive technique to show this? I don't mean to be a burden, but woud you be able to go into more detail on how you thought that out?

Comment: Take a point $(u,v)$ not in the set.  Then $2u^2 - v^2 > 1$.  You can choose an $\epsilon$ small enough so that all the points $(x,y)$ within $\epsilon$ of $(u,v)$ will be such that $2x^2 - v^2 > 1$.  So $u,v$ can not be a limit if $2u^2-v > 1$.  So to be a limit point we must have $2u^2 - v^2\le 1$, i.e. in the set.  SO the set is closed.

Comment: @fleablood two quick questions:  1) How did you pick the idea for $\epsilon$? and 2) how to explicitly show if $(k,j) \in B_{\epsilon}(x,y)$ then $2k^2-j > 1$?  In general with respect to  2) I would work out an explicit expression for this $\epsilon$ for example: $\epsilon = \|(x,y)\| - R$   where $R$   = the radius of my set. But I don't see how that argument could work here.

Comment: The idea for epsilon is standard.  To show something is not a limit point you show there is a distance, $\epsilon$ so that none of the points in $B_\epsilon(x)$ are in the set.  Hence $x$ is not a limit point.  And $2w^2 - v^2 > 1$ then we can use $d=(2w^2 - v^2) -1$ to algebraically come up with a value for $\epsilon$.  To visualize this, draw the curve $2x^2 - y^2 = 1$.  And draw the point $(u,v)$ so that $2u^2 - v^2 >1$.  find the point $(k,j)$ that is on the curve that is closest to  $(u,v)$.  Find the distance from $(k,j)$ to $(u,v)$.  Draw a circle around $(u,v)$ with that as the radius.

Comment: Let $2u^2 -v^2 = 1+d; d > 0$.  Let $e > 0$.  Let $S$ be the square {$(x,y)$ where $u-e < x< u+e$ and $v-e< y< v+e$.  Then $B_e(u,v) \subset S$.  Then if $(j,k) \in S$ then $j^2 < u^2\pm2ue + e^2$. $k^2 > v^2 \mp 2ve + e^2$.  So $2u^2-v^2 > 1 + d - (|\pm 4ue \mp 2ve + 2e^2|)$.  Select an $e$ so that $|\pm 4ue \mp 2ve + 2e^2| < d$.  Then $2u^2 - v^2 > 1 + d - d = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much @fleablood I am going to rework this example that you gave me until it is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This set is unbounded: for each $x>1$, take $y=\sqrt{2x^2-1}$. Then $(x,y)\in A$, but since $x$ can be arbitrarily large… So, $A$ is not compact.

Comment: How would I show the property of it being close? Maybe not specifically for this set, but in general for concrete sets.

Comment: @dc3rd The function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y) = 2x^2 - y^2$ is continuous, and the original set is $f^{-1}((-\infty, 1])$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler although I do know that this method is completely true, I am working through my textbook and up to this point we have not covered continuous functions. So I was looking for a method that did not perhaps include that notion. I have been trying fleablood 's hint, but I cannot seem to get any where with it.....

Answer (score 0):

Lets call your set $H = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : 2x^2 - y^2 \leq 1\}$, because it contains a hyperbola.

Concerning unboundedness:

With $u = \sqrt{2}x-y$ and $v = \sqrt{2}x+y$ you get:
$$2x^2-y^2 = (\sqrt{2}x-y)(\sqrt{2}x+y) = uv = 1$$
So, it's unbounded and, hence, not compact.

Concerning closedness:

Let $(x_0,y_0)= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(x_n,y_n)$ with $(x_n,y_n) \in H$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
You just need to show that $(x_0,y_0) \in H$. But this is easy to show as
$$(x_0,y_0)= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(x_n,y_n) \Leftrightarrow x_0= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n \mbox{ and } y_0= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n$$
It follows immediately

$$2x_0^2 - y_0^2 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (2x_n^2 - y_n^2) \leq 1$$